# print list of tuples without brackets python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples and I want to  print flattened form of this list. I don't want to transform the list, just print it without parenthesis and brackets.

```
input: [ ("a", 1), ("b",2), ("c", 3)]
output:   a 1 b 2 c 3
```

Here's what I do:

```
l = [ ("a", 1), ("b",2), ("c", 3)]
f = lambda x: " ".join(map(str,x))
print " ".join(f(x) for x in l)
```

I'm interested in if anybody has a more elegant and possibly a more efficient solution,possibly without doing join, only print. Thanks in advance.

Comment: join is the easiest way of outputting a list as a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from __future__ import print_function 

l =  [("a", 1), ("b",2), ("c", 3)]

print(*(i for j in l for i in j))
a 1 b 2 c 3
```

Or using itertools.chain to flatten:

```
from itertools import chain

print(*chain(*l))
```

Comment: Yeah, I had no idea you could do that. Yay for Python 3.

Comment: Yay yay yay from me also for Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.join()` you can use a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> print ' '.join([str(i) if isinstance(i,int) else i for tup in A for i in tup])
a 1 b 2 c 3
```

And without `join()` still you need to loop over the the items and concatenate them, which I think `join()` is more pythonic way for this aim.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP is looking for a solution without `join`. Good solution though.

Comment: I edited my question:) I want to avoid operations other than print as much as possible. Solution is nice, though.

Comment: I also think so, but I wanted to ask anyway to see other people's views.

Comment: @dogacanb Checkout Padraic's answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to do this without list flattening operations like `join`, then this will work, but it's terrible and you should just use `join`:

```
[sys.stdout.write(str(i) + ' ' + str(j) + ' ') for (i, j) in input]
```

Using `stdout.write` because it does not automatically append a newline like `print` does.

Answer (score 0):

That's more simple than you can imagine.

```
   a = [ ("a", 1), ("b",2), ("c", 3)]
    for i,j in a:
        print(i,j,end=' ')
```